# Next JS App Router- Passing Client Component As Prop From Sever Component

Tags: next.js, next.js13, app-router, react-server-components

My current understanding is that all props passed from a server component to a client component need to be serializable. This means that a function cannot be passed from a server to a client component. When trying to do this I get an expected error message.

However in the below example I have a server component which renders a client component. That client component takes as a prop another client component. In my understanding this should not work as the component is passed from a server component and is there a function.

Is this a bug in that it works, or an anti pattern, am I misunderstanding something?

```
import ClientComponent from "./ClientComponent";
import ClientCounterView from "./ClientCounterView";

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <ClientComponent CounterView={ClientCounterView}></ClientComponent>
  )
}
```

*page.tsx - A server component*

```
'use client'

import { useState } from 'react'

export default function ClientComponent({CounterView}: {CounterView: React.ComponentType}) {
    const [count, setCount] = useState(0)

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Client Component</h1>
            <CounterView></CounterView>
        </div>
    )
}
```

*ClientComponent - Marked with use client so this is the client server boundry which means its props must be serializable?*

```
'use client'

export default function ClientCounterView() {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Client Counter View</h1>
        </div>
    )
}
```

*ClientCounterView - A client component, if we remove the 'use client' directive we would see an error*